# How can I put the things i select in my listbox in the sheets in one cell?

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
 Dim WS_Count As Integer
  Dim I As Integer ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active workbook.
  WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
  ' Begin the loop.
  For I = 1 To WS_Count
    Sheets(I).Select
    ' Insert your code here.
    Cells(2, 2).Value = ListBox1.Value

  Next I
  AcitveWorkbook.Worksheets.Cells().Value
End Sub
```

How can I put the things i select in my listbox in the sheets in one cell, for example cell B2, and when I change the selection for example ceo instead of cro that the cell is changing again?
thx

Comment: [how to tell if something is selected in listbox](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-6466.html)

Comment: i have a select (all) function for that

Comment: So. What is not working in the code above as you expect it to?

Comment: Can you not just put B2 in the linked cell property of the list box? Then you won't need any code.

Comment: Thx for your help